# Platform specific restrictions

Tags: magento2, product, list

I am looking for information what i can not sell using magento open source. Is there list of forbidden items? This information for my blog article.

Answer (score 0):

While Magento itself, as an e-commerce platform, does not place any restrictions on the type of goods or services you can sell using its platform, it's crucial to note that selling certain items may be regulated or outright banned by:

**Local, state, and federal laws:** Every country and sometimes individual states or regions within countries have their own laws regulating the sale of certain items. This can include restrictions on selling dangerous goods, counterfeit items, firearms, certain healthcare items, etc.

**Payment processors:** Services like PayPal, Stripe, or credit card processors often have rules on the types of goods and services they will process payments for. This can include a ban on selling adult content, firearms, certain supplements, and more.

**Shipping providers:** Certain goods may be restricted or banned by shipping providers. For example, many providers will not ship dangerous goods, perishable items without appropriate packaging, or large/bulky items without additional fees.

**Third-party marketplaces or integrations:** If you're selling on third-party marketplaces like Amazon, eBay, or Etsy via Magento, you'll need to abide by their policies, which might prohibit certain items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know this information, but I'm more interested in the limitations on the platform itself.

Comment: There are no limitations on the platform itself.

Comment: Ok, could you write a source of this information?